# How to do join query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I am having a hard time in ES join query, I googled a lot but find nothing helpful. So I ask here.

#### 1. Mappings

I have 2 index, whose mapping is:

mappings for index logs:

```
"logs": {
        "properties": {
            "timestamp": {"type": "date"},
            "host": {"type": "keyword"},
            "log": {"type": "text"}

}
```

mapping for index versions:

```
"versions": {
        "properties": {
            "host": {"type": "keyword"},
            "version": {"type": "keyword"}

}
```

#### 2. Sample Data

Suppose I have data like this:

Data for logs:

```
timestamp:1, host:a1, log: "sample log1"
timestamp:2, host:a1, log: "sample log2"
timestamp:3, host:a1, log: "sample log3"
timestamp:1, host:a2, log: "sample log4"
timestamp:2, host:a2, log: "sample log5"
timestamp:3, host:a2, log: "sample log6"
timestamp:1, host:a3, log: "sample log7"
timestamp:2, host:a3, log: "sample log8"
timestamp:3, host:a3, log: "sample log9"
```

Data for versions:

```
host:a1, version:v1
host:a2, version:v1
host:a3, version:v2
```

#### 3. Purpose & Expected Result

What I want to query is:
"Find out all logs of host's version equal to v1"

The result should be:

```
timestamp:1, host:a1, log: "sample log1"
timestamp:2, host:a1, log: "sample log2"
timestamp:3, host:a1, log: "sample log3"
timestamp:1, host:a2, log: "sample log4"
timestamp:2, host:a2, log: "sample log5"
timestamp:3, host:a2, log: "sample log6"
```

How should I do it? Please help.

Comment: While using search it would be better approach to keep data in denormalized form rather that in normalised form. That itself would remove the need to join. Another approach could be the use of [join field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/parent-join.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch is not a relational database, and therefore does not support join.

The only ways to workaround this, with many cons, is to either use [parent-child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) (or [join data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) in v6) or [nested docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

** both options are not that scalable and may introduce performance issues.

Comment: I understand elastic search is not a relationship DB. The nested required those to be put in one mapping, which is not proper for me. For the parent-child, could u specify an example for this? I tried but have not figured it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'll need to use has_parent query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/has-parent.html
which will look something like this:
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "version": "1", 
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}

I suggest you'll read the entire parent-child section: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html